# Fasting niyat(dua)

Tags: sawm, niyyah

Asslam o alikum.
In Islam the new day begins after maghrib , right.
When we do sehri and close our fast at fagr , we do the intention(niyat) of fast. From fagr to maghrib(when we open the fast) it is the same day. But the intention(niyat) of fast is:
I intend to keep the fast for tomorrow in the month of Ramadan.
[image]

What is the reason behind this?
Thank you.

Comment: There's no specific du'a nor specific wording for niya for fasting the main idea is to have in mind to fast before actually staring with it. I think this is well covered in my answer of [Can niyat intention be done by heart or must it be declared verbally](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40279/can-niyat-intention-be-done-by-heart-or-must-it-be-declared-verbally) Also note that the niya for one day should be made for this day, so saying you'll fast tomorrow might be correct in your heart, but wrong as you explained the night is the beginning of the actual day ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Prophet ﷺ informed us that for the fasting to be accepted:

1. *Niyyah* (intention) to fast is required.
2. The time of *niyyah* is before the break of dawn of the day one is fasting.

> عن حفصة زوج النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال: مَنْ لَمْ يُجْمِعِ الصِّيَامَ قَبْلَ الْفَجْرِ فَلاَ صِيَامَ لَهُ
>
> Narrated by Hafsah, Ummul Mu'minin, that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "He who does not determine to fast before dawn does not fast."
>
> <sub>— [Sunan Abi Dawud, Book 14, Hadith 142](https://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/14/142)</sub>

[Ibn Taymiyyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Taymiyyah) in his book [*Al-Fatāwa al-Kubra* 5/375](https://al-maktaba.org/book/9690/2280#p4) (Arabic only) said that the intention to fast is not tied to being words that are spoken; rather, a thought or deliberation that one will fast suffices as the intention.

As for the three supplications you provided, none of them is attributed to the Prophet ﷺ, and there are no specific words that are known that the Prophet ﷺ used to form his intention of fasting. The reason for using the words provided is, therefore, unknown as they are unattributed in the first place.