# I slept whole Night and woke up

Tags: sawm, ramadan

Assalammu Allaikum...!!

I slept whole night and I woke up at 4:50AM and kept niyaat for fasting. Is my fasting is valid or not ? My Fajr Adhaan time is 4:30 and Iqamat is 4:45AM. I am worried a lot. Could you please help me. I was not intentionally did this. But it happened

Comment: IMO this is a clear duplicate of [fasting without getting awak at that time](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48247/fasting-without-getting-awake-at-that-time) and the matter of intention is also covered in [Can niyyat be done by heart or must it be declared verbally](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40279/can-niyat-intention-be-done-by-heart-or-must-it-be-declared-verbally) I strongly assume that you had in mind to fast before going to sleep then everything os fine.

Answer (score 0):

Wa Alaykum Assalam Brother.

Prophet Mohammad Said that:

> *Whoever does not have the intention of fasting from the night before, then there is no fast for him.* [22:245](https://sunnah.com/nasai/22/245)

However, the scholars differed in this case as follows:

It says in al-Mawsoo‘ah al-Fiqhiyyah (40/275):

> *The Hanafis, Shaafa‘is and Hanbalis are of the view that forgetting to form the intention on some nights of a fast that must be observed on consecutive days interrupts the sequence, as does omitting it deliberately, and forgetting is not regarded as a valid excuse for failing to do what is obligatory.*
>
> *The Maalikis are of the view that a single intention is acceptable for every fast that must be observed on consecutive days, such as Ramadan.*

In al-Khulaasah al-Fiqhiyyah ‘ala Madhhab as-Saadah al-Maalikiyyah, it says:

> *A single intention is sufficient for every fast which must be observed on consecutive days, such as Ramadan.*

So as you can see, the majority agreed that you should intend to fast every night. Imam Malik however agreed that one intent before Ramadan to fast the whole month is sufficient.

So Unless you intended to fast the whole month before Ramadan, you should make up for this day.

Allah knows best.

Comment: Thanks bro. But i used keep Niyaat after taraweeh. So as i said before did my fasting is valid or not. Please clarify me.

Comment: Yes brother the Hadith is clear, your fasting is valid since you kept niyaat the night before. May Allah bless you with guidance.