# I'm not sure whether my fast for ramadam count. I did not do intention to fast because i was feeling unwell but was able to manage until iftaar

Tags: ramadan

I was having a light fever so I decided to do sehri but I did not make the intention to fast as I was worried whether the fever will worsen and that maybe I will need medication. I did not want to break my fast. However, during the day I feel I can manage until iftaar. Will my fast count or I will have to replace it?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Isn't your question already covered in [Can i fast if I changed my mind during the day no intention to fast or suhoor from the night?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75460/can-i-fast-if-i-changed-my-mind-during-the-day-no-intention-to-fast-or-suhoor-f)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to makeup for that day because of the following statement.

> Allah’s Messenger (ﷺ) said: “Whoever does not commit himself to
> fasting before dawn (fajr), there is no fast for him.” and in a
> narration, “There is no fast for the one who did not make the
> intention to fast from the night.
>
> Abu Dawood no. 2454 (authenticated by Al-Albāni), Ibn Mājah no. 1700,
> Tirmidhi no. 730.

Answer (score 0):

Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidina wa Azimina, Wa Habibi Qulubina wa Shafii Nufusina, Abul Qasim Muhammad. Wa 'ala Ahli Bayti tayyibina tahireen.

---

Refer to following Hadith from Kitab Al-Kafi,

> (It has been narrated) from Abu Abdullah (Imam Jafar As-Sadiq)(asws),
> regarding the man who found that his head hurts from severe headaches.
> Is it allowed for him, the breaking?’ He (asws) said: ‘When the head
> hurts with **a severe headache**, and when he is in fever with **a severe
> fever**, and his eyes are sore with severe soreness, so the breaking
> is Permissible for him’.
>
> Source: [Al Kafi – V 4 – The Book of Fasts Ch 39 H 5](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/AlKafiVol4/Al%20Kafi%20V4%20-%20The%20Book%20of%20Fasts%20(2).pdf)

So in case of **a severe fever** accompanied with **a severe headache** it is permissible to break fast and it will be made up other day according to 2:185. And you say `I was having a light fever` which means it was not a good excuse for you to break.

`I did not make the intention to fast`

But the description of your situation is indicating the opposite. You had your Sehri and You say `I did not want to break my fast` and you felt confident during the day that you could manage. All of these indications mean you had the intention to fast.

The worries and concerns you are experiencing might simply be from Shaitan in your mind.

If you truly had not made the intention to fast then it would have reflected in your actions and You would have done the exact opposite of what you described.