# Is your fast still valid if you forget to perform niyah on that particular day?

Tags: ramadan, niyyah

As the title suggests I sometimes forget to perform the niyah for fasting that particular day but I still fast and often I perform the niyah midday.

> وَبِصَوْمِ غَدٍ نَّوَيْتُ مِنْ شَهْرِ رَمَضَانَ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fasting niyat(dua)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48150/fasting-niyatdua)

Comment: Yep, it does. Can I ask you about the fact not many questions are getting upvoted the last couple of weeks? Does that have to do with the content of them or is this because the reader has pretty high expectations for him/ her to upvote a question? I'm referring to questions that have answers but don't receive any upvotes.

Comment: If you agree that the linked question covers your inquiry, please mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Done.