# question about intention to fast

Tags: practical-islam, sawm, ramadan, niyyah

i learned you can make intention to fast once for the whole month so on the third day of ramadan my fast was broken so i learned you can make an intention to fast for the whole month on the 7th day, today on the 8th i told myself i was gonna make intention when i got out of the bathroom but i forgot so is my intention to fast the rest of the days of ramadan from the 7th also suffice for the lack of intention on the 8th?

Comment: To make intention means you know in your heart that you are going to fast.

Comment: so like if i told my brother to wake me up 10 mins before fajr does that count as intention

Comment: Your inquiry is covered in [Can niyat intention be done by heart or must it be declared verbally?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40279/can-niyat-intention-be-done-by-heart-or-must-it-be-declared-verbally)