# Is wudu invalid if you didn’t explicit form niyyah sentence in your head?

Tags: wudu, niyyah

My question is, is it enough to just have the intention to do wudu and say Bismilliah or does it have to be something like ,,Allah I am taking the intention to do wudu (for you / in order to pray)“? What is the ruling for a person that has prayed a lot prayers but didn’t form that kind of sentence in their head?

Comment: You should have the niyyah in your heart, you do not have to say out.

Comment: Yes thats right. I do not mean with saying out loud, my question is rather if forming  a sentence of niyyah (in mind) is required

Comment: really the same thing..

Comment: So just having the intention to do wudu without forming an explicit sentence like mentioned above is sufficient?

Comment: Correct. It's not that complicated

Comment: Isn't this topic sufficiently covered in [Can niyat intention be done by heart or must it be declared verbally?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40279/can-niyat-intention-be-done-by-heart-or-must-it-be-declared-verbally)

Comment: It is not the same